# NAS frozen when Media Server enabled. Normal or not?

Tags: freeze, nas, media, dlna

I have a Network Attached Storage (NAS), with 8TB of storage. Currently 4TB in use. It's a Lenovo, model IX4-300D.

Having recently bought a smart TV, I became aware that I could use the TV to directly access the NAS: however this required "DLNA" to be enabled. Apparently this is an additional service required for some devices, over and above the simple ability to connect to the SMB share. According to a couple of sources, the way to do this was to enable the "media server" on my NAS.

On the NAS' control panel, I therefore toggled the option to enable the media server. The screen greyed out and the word "Processing" appeared. However, it then stopped responding.

It has now been in a non-responsive state for several hours. On the hardware itself, the LCD time display is frozen at the time I tried to turn on the media server. Otherwise, the Power light is on, and the Disk Activity light is also solidly on - although I saw it flash briefly.

I can ping the NAS' IP, and get a response. However if I try to refresh the control panel page via my browser, it times out. Similarly, I am unable to access any of the files via Windows Explorer. It seems that the machine is on the network, but the http server and file servers are not responding.

This suggests that the action of switching on the media server is actually doing something to my data. Scanning it perhaps? Although I'm unsure of why the simple action of enabling a media server would necessitate a full scan of all the files.

My question is whether this is normal, expected behaviour - or if it seems that something's wrong, and I should try to reset it. I don't want to reset prematurely, in case it interrupts a legitimate operation (which may then have to start all over again when the machine restarts). I also don't want to wait for an interminable period, waiting for something to finish, when it could also be the case that it's simply frozen. What worries me especially is how the LCD panel on the hardware is frozen.

I realise that hardware-specific advice would normally go via the help forums for the relevant manufacturer. I have indeed posted this question on the forums. However the activity there seems minimal, and therefore I thought I would also turn to the good people of Stack Exchange.

If anyone out there has experience of NAS media servers, perhaps they could advise? Is it normal for a NAS to want to scan the entire file system for something like this?

As a wider point - in others' experience, how long would a scan of 4TB of data take? It's stored over 4 x 2TB drives, spinning at (I believe) 7200rpm - arranged in RAID5.

Any advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

After several days, the NAS was still frozen in place. I therefore rebooted it - and am happy to report that the system started as normal. Crucially, all my files were intact.

I'm still left with a mystery as to what caused the freeze, but I gather this was not normal behaviour.